# Xcode : How to add support OS 3.0 in XCode 3.2.3

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

Is there any way to detect the SDK prior to 3.1.3 in the latest XCode that is 3.2.3.

Looking for answers.

Thank You.

Comment: The iPhone OS 4.0 betas are still under NDA, so answering this question would be a violation of one's developer agreement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you haven't found it already, here is a good article on how to set it up

http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/07/tips-tricks-for-conditional-ios3-ios32.html